# Android - How to prevent sms every 1 second?

Tags: java, android, sms

I'm in an android project that in this I wanna prevent sms from some numbers that receive messages before go into inbox per second. Now I help that guide me how I can work this project programmatically? 
I see some sample codes but I don't know how I can...

Comment: You can not do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that on modern versions of Android.  On older versions you could, but as of 4.3 or 4.4 Android introduced the concept of the default sms app.  Only that app can write to the SMS database.  And you cannot programatically set the default SMS app, only the user can set it manually.

Now if this restriction is ok with you, you can do it as the default SMS app.  Whenever you receive an SMS, you need to write it to the database.  If you don't write it, it won't appear in the inbox.  You can then decide when to write messages or even to silently delete messages.

Comment: It's 4.4, if you want to be specific.

Comment: I knew it was on of those, just too lazy to look it up.  Thanks.